# "sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat" error every time trying to install using pip

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pip

I just installed Python 2.7.5 on my Windows 10 machine and I also got pip installed through setuptools. However whenever I try to install something using pip e.g. `pip install numpy`, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    __import__('pip._vendor.packaging.specifiers')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 275, in <module>
    class Specifier(_IndividualSpecifier):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 373, in Specifier
    r"^\s*" + _regex_str + r"\s*$", re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Since I'm pretty new to Python, I don't really understand what this error means. Any workaround?

Comment: The problem is coming from the `_regex_str` that is used as a regex pattern. If it contains something like `|?` or `(?` then the issue appears. It must be `re.escape(_regex_str)` if the literal string match is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a library that is using regular expressions (with the re.compile() function). I solved this issue installing the last version available 2.7.13 (I run a Windows 7).
Before I had the 2.7.6 version. I updated it installing the new version with the .msi installer, available in the Python web page.